# How limited is the Linux-based distribution on the Nokia n900?

Tags: linux, maemo, mobile

I am interested what N900 can do with Linux-based Maemo 5 system installed.

Can it for example:

1. Compile c++ or java files?
2. Hack into wifi (I meant advanced wlan card features)
3. Create own wifi access point?
4. Be WWW server?
5. Use normal usb keyboard? (after changing plug into smaller)
6. Play flash games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS is basically a customised version of Debian, and that means that whatever Debian can do, your N900 can. That's because you can run normal Debian packages on it, and even use official APT sources. As for the hardware part, stuff like point 2 and point 5, I just don't know.

Note that [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N900) is quite detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely - I have a colleague who has successfully used it for wireless 'hacking' - it works really well, utilising the tools we normally use on our laptops for this.

as @Tshepang says, it is just Debian, cut down a wee bit, so if the default install doesn't come with what you need, apt-get is your friend.

Sadly, I also don't know whether it has USB master on board, but for everything else you asked - yep (although compile times could be very long - use a cross compiler :-)